# How to run the Topics RViz plugin

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, plugin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Continuing the discussion from [Topics RViz plugin](https://discourse.ros.org/t/topics-rviz-plugin/5030):
You can check the package [here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/topics-rviz-plugin/5030?u=harderthan)

Hello.
I’m a beginner on ROS. So, I have this question.

I downloaded this plugin at my workspace. After build it using catkin_make, I tried to run this plugin directly.
But, I can’t it. **The prompt can not found binary file for this plugin.**

I checked CMakeLists.txt and package.xml. But, I don’t know how to run this exactly.
It sounds like a basic question about ros, could you tell me how to fix this?

// ENV: Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295760/how-to-run-the-topics-rviz-plugin/) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a plugin for rviz, not a standalone program, so you load it from within rviz.

After you've built the package and sourced the workspace where you built it, start rviz. There should be a `Panel` menu, and from there you should be able to find a menu option that will let you add the Topics panel to the rviz display.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2018-06-29**:
Cool! Thank you for your answer.